# Webpack-dev-server and isomorphic react-node application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, isomorphic-javascript, webpack-dev-server

I've managed to properly use webpack dev server alongside with a node server (express), using the plugin section inside webpack's config.

It all works fine but now I'm trying to go isomorphic and use client-side components inside the express application.

So far the only problem I'm encountering is that without webpack 'parsing' my server-side code I get to a situation where I require components but the paths are not solved

I.E.

**Inside a component**

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import { RouteHandler, Link } from 'react-router';
import Header from 'components/header/main'; // <-- This line causes the error because webpack is not working when parsing this JSX server-side

export default React.createClass({
    displayName: 'App',
    render() {
        return ( // ... More code
```

Shall I configure webpack in another way or do I have to change all the imports to be valid server-side?

the codebase is here in case you want to see the actual state https://github.com/vshjxyz/es6-react-flux-node-quickstart

Comment: Why don't you compile your webpack code to node (commonjs)?
http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 options:

1. Compile client code with webpack as well. If client's entry
   point is in the same dir as server's - it should work with your
   present code. This looks natural to me.
2. Use relative paths i.e.
   `import Header from './components/header/main'`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried with relative paths but the problem is that I also import css files inside my jsx (see https://github.com/vshjxyz/es6-react-flux-node-quickstart/blob/master/app/components/header/main.jsx for instance)... and I haven't really understood your first point - client-side is already using webpack, problem is that the node server is not!

Comment: How do you compile your node app with webpack? I can't see this in your repo. You're able to `import ... 'components/...'` because of this line in conifg https://github.com/vshjxyz/es6-react-flux-node-quickstart/blob/master/webpack/dev.config.js#L72 . You must have the same line in your server-side compiling config (which I can't see). Then it should work. I believe it's your best option keeping in mind that you also import css.

Comment: If you don't want to compile node with webpack another option is to move to relative paths and check if it's browser before requiring CSS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347722/importing-css-files-in-isomorphic-react-components/30355080#30355080

Comment: Yes I know they problem stands on using modulesDirectories with webpack and not in node, I tought it was a webpack-specific option? Thanks for clarifying the css imports only if browser, now I know why I saw some projects with that. I'm trying to figure out why projects like https://github.com/iam4x/isomorphic-flux-boilerplate are not using relative paths (but sort of what I've configured) and yet they can render server-side

Comment: Seems like this makes it possible `process.env.NODE_PATH = 'app';`. https://github.com/iam4x/isomorphic-flux-boilerplate/blob/master/server/index.js#L9 But you still have to check if it's browser when requiring css

Comment: Here's the description of this method https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520#6-the-hack

Answer (score 3):

In order to be able to require components in a way such as `require('components/Header.js');` and avoid using long relative paths such as `require('../../../../../../Header.js');` you can add this code to your node app before any require() calls:

```
process.env.NODE_PATH = __dirname;
require('module').Module._initPaths();
```

> However, since this relies on a private Node.js core method, this is
>   also a hack that might stop working on the previous or next version of
>   node.

Other possible solutions to this problem can be found at https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520