# Unable to import (require) css, less, sass file on react component when using express server

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, server-side-rendering, less-loader

I'm importing less or css file to my react component and it is working fine on my following example project:
https://github.com/digz6666/webpack-loader-test

But when I use express server to implement SSR I no longer can import less file to my react component. It is only working on index.js entry file.
It throws following exception:

```
[1] Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0)
[1] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
[1] | // @import '~antd/dist/antd.css';
[1] > .trigger {
[1] |   font-size: 18px;
[1] |   line-height: 64px;
[1]     at eval (webpack:///./src/client/layout/baseLayout.less?:1:7)
```

Here's the example project that I use SSR:
https://github.com/digz6666/webpack-loader-test/tree/ssr

Please uncomment styles in following file, npm install and npm start to test:

```
/src/client/layout/baseLayout.less
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader because its easier to configure. Also I've added the code here:
https://github.com/digz6666/webpack-loader-test/tree/ssr-2

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, my app is isomorphic so I need isomorphic loaders.
Following is answered my question: [How to import CSS file on Isomorphic React - Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489192/how-to-import-css-file-on-isomorphic-react-webpack)

I should use https://github.com/catamphetamine/universal-webpack as the https://github.com/catamphetamine/webpack-isomorphic-tools is not maintained anymore.