# How to correctly configure React-Toolbox in an isomorphic web application without "asset not found" error

Tags: node.js, sass, react-toolbox, webpack-isomorphic-tools

I am a beginner to webpack, node.js and basically to web development. I am using [Redux/React/Isomorphic boilerplate](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) . I am trying to use [React-Toolbox](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox) for all the presentation components but not able to build/bundle (npm run dev) as it throws an error - "assets not found". Please help me fix this issue. I have given below all the errors/config details

**Errors on running - 'npm run dev'**:

```
[2] ==> ? API is running on port 3030
[2] ==> ? Send requests to http://localhost:3030
[1] [webpack-isomorphic-tools] [error] asset not found: ./node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/ripple/style.scss
[1] [webpack-isomorphic-tools] [error] asset not found: ./node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/button/style.scss
[0] ./src/containers/Survey/Survey.js
[0] 
[0] C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Dev Work\MYAPP-REDUX\src\containers\Survey\Survey.js
[0] 6:8 error "Button" is defined but never used no-unused-vars
[0] 
[0] ? 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
[0] 
[0] ./~/css-loader?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local][hash:base64:5]!./~/autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 version!./~/sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap!./~/react-toolbox/lib/button/s
tyle.scss
[0] Module build failed:
[0] undefined
[0] ^
[0] Import directives may not be used within control directives or mixins.
[0] in C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Dev Work\MYAPP-REDUX\node_modules\react-toolbox\lib_base.scss (line 4, column 3)
[0] Error:
[0] undefined
[0] ^
[0] Import directives may not be used within control directives or mixins.
[0] in C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Dev Work\MYAPP-REDUX\node_modules\react-toolbox\lib_base.scss (line 4, column 3)
[0] at options.error (C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Dev Work\MYAPP-REDUX\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:271:32)
[0] @ ./~/react-toolbox/lib/button/style.scss 4:14-272 13:2-17:4 14:20-278
[0] ./~/css-loader?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local][hash:base64:5]!./~/autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 version!./~/sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap!./~/react-toolbox/lib/ripple/s
tyle.scss
[0] Module build failed:
[0] undefined
[0] ^
[0] Import directives may not be used within control directives or mixins.
[0] in C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Dev Work\MYAPP-REDUX\node_modules\react-toolbox\lib_base.scss (line 4, column 3)
[0] Error:
[0] undefined
[0] ^
[0] Import directives may not be used within control directives or mixins.
[0] in C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Dev Work\MYAPP-REDUX\node_modules\react-toolbox\lib_base.scss (line 4, column 3)
[0] at options.error (C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Dev Work\MYAPP-REDUX\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:271:32)
[0] @ ./~/react-toolbox/lib/ripple/style.scss 4:14-272 13:2-17:4 14:20-278
[0] [webpack-isomorphic-tools/plugin] [error] Module "./~/css-loader?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local][hash:base64:5]!./~/autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 version!./~/sass-loader?outputStyle
=expanded&sourceMap!./~/react-toolbox/lib/ripple/style.scss" has no source. Maybe Webpack compilation of this module failed. Skipping this asset.
[0] [webpack-isomorphic-tools/plugin] [error] Module "./~/css-loader?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local][hash:base64:5]!./~/autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 version!./~/sass-loader?outputStyle
=expanded&sourceMap!./~/react-toolbox/lib/button/style.scss" has no source. Maybe Webpack compilation of this module failed. Skipping this asset.
[0] webpack built 7d8176b687a8306c3338 in 18755ms
```

**Survey.js:**

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import {initialize} from 'redux-form';
import {SurveyForm} from 'components';
import Button from 'react-toolbox/lib/button';
.... rest of the code omitted as the above import causes this..
```

**Webpack config:**

```
chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
publicPath: 'http://' + host + ':' + port + '/dist/'
},
module: {
loaders: [
{ test: /.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel?' + JSON.stringify(babelLoaderQuery), 'eslint-loader']},
{ test: /.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
{ test: /.less$/, loader: 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local][hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!less?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap' },
{
test: /.scss$/,
loader: 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local][hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap',
//include: /node_modules/react-toolbox/
},
{ test: /.woff(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
{ test: /.woff2(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
{ test: /.ttf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
{ test: /.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
{ test: /.svg(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
{ test: webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.regular_expression('images'), loader: 'url-loader?limit=10240' }
]
},
progress: true,
resolve: {
modulesDirectories: [
'src',
'node_modules',
//path.join(dirname, '../node_modules')
],
extensions: ['', '.json', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss', ]
},
plugins: [
// hot reload
new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/webpack-stats.json$/),
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
__CLIENT: true,
SERVER: false,
DEVELOPMENT: true,
DEVTOOLS: true // <-------- DISABLE redux-devtools HERE
}),
webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.development()
]
};
```

**webpack-isomorphic-tools config:**

```
style_modules: {
  include: [/^\.\/node_modules\/*/],
  extensions: ['less','scss'],
  filter: function(module, regex, options, log) {
    if (options.development) {
      // in development mode there's webpack "style-loader",
      // so the module.name is not equal to module.name
      return WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.style_loader_filter(module, regex, options, log);
    } else {
      // in production mode there's no webpack "style-loader",
      // so the module.name will be equal to the asset path
      return regex.test(module.name);
    }
  },
  path: function(module, options, log) {
    if (options.development) {
      // in development mode there's webpack "style-loader",
      // so the module.name is not equal to module.name
      return WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.style_loader_path_extractor(module, options, log);
    } else {
      // in production mode there's no webpack "style-loader",
      // so the module.name will be equal to the asset path
      return module.name;
    }
  },
  parser: function(module, options, log) {
    if (options.development) {
      return WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.css_modules_loader_parser(module, options, log);
    } else {
      // in production mode there's Extract Text Loader which extracts CSS text away
      return module.source;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you run `npm install`?

Comment: Yes I did that. If I comment the line ( import Button from 'react-toolbox/lib/button';), bundling happens without any errors.

Comment: And react-toolbox is in your node_modules directory? 

ie) You ran `npm install --save react-toolbox`

Comment: Yes.. PFB the extract from my packages.json
`code`
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.29.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^3.1.0",
    "react-inline-css": "^2.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "2.4.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.23.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-toolbox": "^0.16.2",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-connect": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-form": "^3.0.12",
    "scroll-behavior": "^0.3.2",
    "serialize-javascript": "^1.1.2",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0", `code`

Comment: Alright just a sec, I'll clone it and see what's up

Comment: Thanks Brad for your time. You can clone this pull request as he updated the react dependencies to the latest and it works fine - https://github.com/medfreeman/react-redux-universal-hot-example

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the issue specifically seems to be that you are requiring css in your component (indirectly through React Toolbox) that is attempting to render on the server-side (which is what webpack-isomporphic-tools is handling) instead of the client, where it belongs.

You can reference this question for a potential solution: [Importing CSS files in Isomorphic React Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347722/importing-css-files-in-isomorphic-react-components)

As you've mentioned that you're fairly new to web development, I'd would also suggest that the boilerplate here is massive overkill for early learning / experimentation (isomorphism can be tricky even for experienced developers) and something a bit simpler like https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate or just putting together some simple components from scratch would probably be a more comfortable starting point for learning.