# Webpack React externals not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I can't seem to get webpack's externals configuration for React correctly

The app works when react is imported as a vendor bundled from node_modules.
But when I remove the vendor bundle and try to use react from a CDN I get the following error.

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in. printWarning @ react.js:3640
>   warning @ react.js:3664 createElement @ react.js:2357 module.exports @
>   app.js:122
>   **webpack_require** @ app.js:20 (anonymous) @ app.js:429
>   **webpack_require** @ app.js:20 module.exports @ app.js:66 (anonymous) @ app.js:69

Full Code at https://github.com/ericnoguchi/react-testing

Here is my webpack config

```
let LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');
let ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
let webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': './@Client.js',
        // 'vendor': [
        //     "react",
        //     "react-dom",
        //     "react-router"
        // ],
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/_dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    externals: {
        "react": 'React',
        "react-dom": 'ReactDOM',
        "react-router": 'ReactRouter'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: '_dist'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: [
                        "react",
                        "es2015",
                        "stage-2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                BROWSER: JSON.stringify(true)
            }
        }),
        // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        //     name: 'vendor',
        //     filename: 'vendor.js',
        //     minChunks: Infinity
        // }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("css/[name].css"),
        new LiveReloadPlugin()
    ]
};
```

And there is the layout component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347722/importing-css-files-in-isomorphic-react-components
if (process.env.BROWSER) {
  require('./layout.scss');
  console.log('lalala')
}

export class Layout extends Component {
  handleClick() {
    alert(0);
  }
  render() {
    let {custom, children} = this.props;
    return (
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>{custom.title}</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1>{custom.title}</h1>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
          {children}
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Index</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/foo">404</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>


          <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: 'window.PROPS=' + JSON.stringify(custom)
          }}></script>
          {/*<script src="vendor.js"></script>*/}
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js" />
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js" />
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/3.0.2/react-router.js" />
          <script src="app.js" />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

Client APP

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import routes from './routes/routes.jsx'

ReactDOM.render(routes, document);
```

[image: Error with source maps]

Comment: Not related to your question, but how you asked it; this is relevant [reading for you](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: Where is your `ReactDOM.render` call? (keep all code relevant in the question). Can you enable source maps so you can better see where the actual error is (and show us? app.js:line does not help given that it's a build artifact)

Comment: @Dan Pantry I enabled webpacks dev tool source maps but it does not appear to be of any help see image

Comment: Did you check this https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/ ?

Answer (score -2):

React is working just fine judging by the error you're pasting. Your problem is somewhere else.

There are however multiple flaws in your code. First of all it's not very common to generate the full page from React, and I see your `html`, `head`and `body` tags inside your `render` method.

Second, if you're loading the React CDN scripts **from** React, how is that supposed to work? :) It's a miracle you're getting that error at all.

Have an index.html with the basic HTML skeleton. If you're doing server-side rendering, have a simple template do the same and embed your server-side rendering of the React in a `<div id="app"></div>` placeholder.

Comment: Yes I am using server side rendering so the react scripts should load as the server returns the full page rendered. What I don't understand is why it does not work with CDN but works if I use react from a Webpack vendor chunk which will be a script that goes over app.js. So its basically the same setup.

Comment: You're likely missing an `export default` in one of your components used in your `routes` then.