# How to get hosting URL of a CSS file in NextJs

Tags: next.js, webpack-file-loader

I needed to host a CSS file and load it to an iFrame on the page. I have successfully used `file-loader` in a Preact project. But when I use it in NextJs, it does not work. It does not give any error. Actually, it gives a relative path of the CSS file, but when I try to open the URL by appending the host. NextJs return 404.

Below is the core code:

```
import globalCssUrl from '!!file-loader!../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // !!! /_next/f13a8c0924aa251b14eabf89c510c544.css
  // but http://localhost:300/_next/f13a8c0924aa251b14eabf89c510c544.css gives 404
  console.log(globalCssUrl)

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

I have also created a sample project at here: https://github.com/ZenUml/next-app-get-hosting-url-of-a-file

PS. why not just put it in public? 
In this demo, it is a local CSS file. In my real use case, it is a CSS file from node_module. I needed to use package management to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

You have `/public` folder in your project, for showing purposes. So, you can put your `.css file` in `/public` directory and get access to it from external paths.

Imagine you have created `/public/css/myCSS.css` file.

In your `_app.js` you can add this CSS to your project `import "../public/css/myCSS.css";` and you can access it from as `{yourWebsite}/css/myCSS.css`

P.S. if it's css from `package`, you create a page, import `css file` from `package` in variable and showing this css on page you created. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347722/importing-css-files-in-isomorphic-react-components)